# Perl file extension

Tags: perl

We have few files which don't have the standard perl extension like cgi etc.
Couple of them end with ***.cfm** and have perl code in them.

Now i am not sure why the developer decided to use a coldfusion extension and decide to use perl in it, but we are at a point now where we cannot alter the filename and we need to make some configuration changes such that perl is able to render *.cfm files too.

Is there a way we can modify the perl configuration to accept *.cfm files and render them as perl scripts?

Comment: It is not programming question.

Comment: Perl doesn't care what the extension is. `perl script.cfm` will try to run whatever is in `script.cfm` just fine. However, it sounds like your web server or OS probably does. Perl is not your problem.

Comment: egrunin - We have Solaris as our OS

Comment: wk - I am sorry if i have used the wrong category here

zostay - can you help me what configurations i need to look at considering we are using Solaris?

Answer (score 4):

I'll go out on a limb and guess that your actually asking about running ".cfm" files as CGI scripts, through Apache. In that case, you would use a "handler" to tell Apache to treat *all* *.cfm files as Perl scripts. If I've guessed what's going on, then add this to your Apache 2.2 configuration:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cfm
```

Also, make sure the Perl scripts have the right "shebang" line on the first line, usually:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

If you want some *.cfm files to be still be treated as Cold Fusion, then you'll need a different solution.